# Proving an implication about sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to (dis-)prove the following statement:

$((\mathit{A-B})= \varnothing )\Rightarrow \mathit{A = B}$

I guess that this is shown by comparing their cardinality, but have no idea how to start this.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: The statement is false, and you need to find one counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Recall that "$A=B$" is equivalent to "$A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$".

On the other hand, "$A\setminus B = \varnothing$" is equivalent to "$A\subseteq B$" (show this!).

Answer (score 1):

**Another hint:**  Consider the necessity of understanding the size of $B-A$ in addition to what is given.

Answer (score 0):

$A=\{1\}, B=\{1,2\}$. Note that the difference are the elements in A but not in B